# Stata difference in difference univariate tests

Tags: stata

I want to calculate univariate t-statistic for difference-in-difference.

I have unbalenced panel dataset including treatment and control groups, as follows:

```
                  Treatment   Control  

 Pre-period         5.33       8.9     

 Post-period        5.10       6.9
```

From the above database, I would like to get

```
                  Treatment   Control  Difference

 Pre-period         5.33       8.9     -3.57

 Post-period        5.10       6.9     -1.8

 Difference         0.23       2.0     -1.77
```

Of course, I would like to get t-statistics for each of differences (in total, 5).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let

```
    D(,pre) = [Treat,Pre]    - [Control,Pre]
   D(,post) = [Treat,Post]   - [Control,Post]
  D(treat,) = [Treat,Post]   - [Treat,Pre]
D(control,) = [Control,Post] - [Control,Pre]
        DID = D(post) - D(pre) = D(treat) - D(control).
```

In your example, `D(,pre)` = -3.57, `D(,post)` = -1.8, `D(treat,)` = -0.23, `D(control,)` = -2.0 and `DID` = 1.77. *(Note: We go post-pre rather than pre-post.)* Let "Treat", "Control", "Pre" and "Post" be the four dummy variables.

1. `reg y Treat##Post` gives `D(,pre)`, `D(control,)` and `DID`.
2. `reg y Control##Post` gives `-D(,pre)`, `D(treat,)` and `DID`.
3. `reg y Treat##Pre` gives `D(,post)`, `-D(control,)` and `DID`.
4. `reg y Control##Pre` gives `-D(,post)`, `-D(treat,)` and `DID`.

Explanation: Do `reg y Treat Post c.Treat#c.Post`. The coefficient of `Treat` is `E(y|Treat=1, Post=0) - E(y|Treat=0, Post=0)`, which is `D(,pre)`. The coefficient of `Post` is `E(y|Treat=0, Post=1) - E(y|Treat=0, Post=0)`, which is `D(control,)`. The coefficient on the interaction term is `DID` obviously. Others are similar.